# Calculate number of rows of base fact table

Tags: rows, calculation, fact-table

I would like to get some helpful insight about a situation I stuck.
I try to calculate the number of rows of a fact table.

Time Dimension      : 10 years

Branch Dimension        : 3000 branches in 35 countries

Product Dimension       : 1000 products in each branch. 30 Makes, 180 Models (30 product sell in each branch daily, also daily number of deliveries from each warehouse to each branch)

Supplier Dimension      : 10 suppliers

Warehouse Dimension : 95 Warehouses around the world.( 200,000 Products in              each warehouse)

•   One customer makes at most one purchase of single product in a single day.

10(years) * 365(days) * 3,000(branches) * 10(suppliers) * 30(max sales per product, per branch, per supplier, per day) * 95(Warehouse) = 156,037,500,000 (roughly more than 156 Billion records)

Is my calculation correct?
thanks in advance for your help.
Regards,

Answer (score -1):

There are 365 days in a year. So you may want to fix that...

Other then that, What are you trying to calculate purchases, products? Declare the grain...

Comment: Thanks Chris for the response. I try to calculate products, that's the grain.

Comment: Product is unlikely to be the grain of your fact table, it is more likely to be something like purchases per customer per day. Assuming that is the grain, the max number of records in your fact table (with only 1 purchase per customer per day) would be: no. of customers x 365 x 10

Comment: Hi Nick, sales is the grain of the fact table.

Comment: But you stated "One customer makes at most one purchase of single product in a single day.." so either that is your grain or that statement is not correct

Comment: @Chris. -1 You posted a correction of the question and another question as an answer?